# How can I get the SqlDbType or DbType from IModel in EntityFramework Core 2?

Tags: entity-framework-core

My use case is:

I have a graph of objects from many entities in Entity Framework Core 2 (EFC 2). In EFC 2, the SaveChanges Operation is very slow. The reason appears to be the limit in number of parameters that Sql Server can receieve per query. As Sql Server receive 2100 parameters per query, saving hundreds of thousands of registers must cause many roundtrips, with much latency implied. See issue [2484](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2484) for more information. My current solution is to generate a SqlCommand with a query with Table Valued Parameters (TVP). The plan is to use only one query with a TVP for each table and operation (insert, update and delete), using only one roundtrip for save all the changes. EFC cannot do that actually.

In theory, i'm almost finish this, but i have a problem. To use TVP, i must get the SqlDbType for each column from my Table Type. The Table Types are generated using the metadata in the IModel from EFC. But, i cant get the SqlDbType. Simplified, I tried with:

```
var typeMapper = new SqlServerTypeMapper(new RelationalTypeMapperDependencies());
var entityType = context.Model.GetEntityTypes().First();
var prop = entityType.GetProperties().First();
var mapping = typeMapper.GetMapping(prop);
var dbType = mapping.DbType;
```

Having *dbType*, the plan is get the SqlDbType from *dbType* using a Dictionary. The problem is dbType is getting null.

I'm searched in the api, and i can get the way to extract a SqlType from IModel. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you [tried](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7717)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried, but the code doesn't compile. I think the api is changed in EFC 2.

Comment: @gabomgp You are right, the API is changed. Your code works, but `mapping.DbType` is defined as nullable, and has value for some types (`int`, `byte`, `DateTime`, `Guid`, `byte[]` etc.) but not for other (`bool`, `decimal`, `TimeSpan`, `double`, `string` etc.). I have no idea what's the rule and how are you supposed to use that property. Probably you should ask in their GitHub tracker.